# Inserting data from TextBox

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to insert the data from two TextBoxes into a databse using LINQ to SQL.
I have the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    Customer cust = new Customer();
    cust.FirstName = textBox1.Text;
    cust.LastName = textBox1.Text;

    db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(cust);
    db.SubmitChanges(); 
}
```

When I run the program nothing happens, I don't get any errors and nothing gets saved to the database. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Where do you have this code? Is it in a `Click`-event on a button?

Comment: The code is for a button click event.

Comment: Did you try to debug to see if your handler is executed ?

Comment: Why are you using LINQ to SQL 5 years old? Why not modern Entity Framework?

Comment: I'm new to programming and LINQ to SQL seemed easier to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The code was actually working fine. I had to add the database from the Debug folder to the Database Explorer to view the entered records.